# Setting the PS column delimiter on OSX (BSD)

Tags: bash, macos, sed, ps, bsd

Im working on a script that needs to parse the data returned by a `ps` command. On Redhat/Centos, I know its easy to specify the column delimiter, but with the [BSD version of PS](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3), its not so simple.

I know it would be possible to use `awk`, `sed` or `tr` to replace spaces with whatever character, but lets say the format has `args` or `comm` somewhere in the middle, the output would be:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,args,user | head
  PID  PPID ARGS                                                             USER
60140   494 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp jdoe
60144 60141 -bash                                                            jdoe
55574   494 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp jdoe
55576 55575 -bash                                                            jdoe
20710   494 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp jdoe
20712 20711 -bash                                                            jdoe
66703   494 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp jdoe
66707 66704 -bash                                                            jdoe
66881   494 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp jdoe
```

As you can see, the data in the `args` column can have spaces, which throws the whole thing off.

Whats really irritating, is I actually found a solution that seemed to work just fine, without having to do something like put `args` on the end of the output, but I cant remember the solution, or find it again.

I was thinking that maybe it would be possible to use the column header row to determine the width of the columns, since the headers align with the column data, but I'm sure there's a simpler solution than that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just `args` as the last column, and read data with `Awk`? Can you use it that way?

Comment: The only foolproof delimiter would be a null character.

Comment: What do you actually want to DO with this data? What's your end game? Let's see if we can figure out how to achieve your goal, rather than just send you down what might be the wrong path.

Comment: Also, the link to the man page in your question is actually a view of the SuSE Linux version of `ps`, not the one in either OS X or any current version of FreeBSD.

Comment: Maybe use **homebrew** to install the GNU version of `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -o pid,ppid,args,user \
 awk -v Rpl='_' '
    # line but the header
    NR > 1 {
       p = $1
       P = $2
       u = $NF
       A = $0
         sub( "^[[:blank:]*" p "[[:blank:]*" P "[[:blank:]*", "", A)
         sub( "[[:blank:]*" u "[[:blank:]*$", "", A)
       gsub( " ", Rpl, A)

       # recreate the line
       $0 = sprintf( "%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", p, P, A, u)
       }

    # print the line
    7
    '
```

Notes:

- I use extra code than necessary to show where and how to take the info, p, P and U can be directly be $1, ...
- I recreate the line, you can print it directly. It's in the case you would like to treat the line or content and be the more explicit.
- 7 is a non 0 (private joke, 1 is enough and not confusing) that have as default action to print the current line
- Rpl content ( assigned outside awk to allow batch interaction) is the pattern that will replace the space could be anything (empty is also available).
- i use `\t` as new separator, could be anything else.
- adapt if other field of the ps are used but will not work if several have potential space inside.

Comment: Some of the values in the `args` column will have spaces, which this merges together. Do you know of a way to fix that? Maybe in the `args` column, replace spaces with something like `||`, then when outputting them, replace `||` with a space. But other than that, this is definitely better than what I had.

Comment: Edit: I didnt completely look into the logic before posting the above. But if the columns get moved around, this wont work, correct? I should have posted that, but I need to be able to move the columns around.

Comment: the only constrain i to define where is the spaced field and if there is only 1, you could assume place of the others like here. The easiest, if possible is to order field to have the spaced one (ARGS here) at the last place so other are very easy to catch and filter

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your `bsd ps` does not support the option `--libxo` as advised in my previous answer, you could always use classic bash approach , by putting the spaced args in the end.

You can then use a loop to read the whole ps output in an array, and then you can print the tasks in whatever order you want by adjusting the printing of the corresponding array items.

But for "parsing" you need to keep spaced args in the end. For printing , you just print the array in different order.

See this test  , and mind the spaces in array element No7,11,15:

```
$ while read -r pid ppid user args;do \
psdata+=( "$pid" "$ppid" "$user" "$args" ); \
done< <(ps -o pid,ppid,user,args)

$ declare -p psdata  #let's ask bash to print the array for us
declare -a psdata=([0]="PID" [1]="PPID" [2]="USER" [3]="COMMAND" [4]="769" \
[5]="1" [6]="root" [7]="/usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv0" [8]="770" [9]="1" \
[10]="root" [11]="/usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv1" [12]="771" [13]="1" [14]="root" \
[15]="/usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv2" [16]="772" [17]="1" [18]="root" \
# more items here
```

Answer (score -1):

PS utility at latest FreeBSD11 has `--libxo` option that can be used to format the output of `ps` in xml,text,json etc. Though this option  will not be available in ps utility that comes from earlier bsd (i.e openbsd 6 or freebsd less than 11).

If --libxo is available one workaround could be to use `ps --libxo json` and then use `jq` to retrieve the values you need,or use another tool like `sed`.

See this test:

```
$ ps --libxo json -o pid,args |tr '}' '\n' |sed 's/["{:]//g;s/arguments//g;s/pid//g;s/^,//g'

804,-csh (csh)
813,dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session
816,xinit /usr/local/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc
817,X 0 (Xorg)
819,sh /usr/local/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc
825,xfce4-session
.....................................................
```

You can further `cut` the formatted stram and extract fields based on comma delimiter ( i.e pipe above output `|cut -d, -f2` will give you only the args)

Offcourse if you know how to work with jq you don't need all these pipes and seds, you can extract the fields directly from the json stream.

Also, you can have a look in `man xo_parse_args` for more options about the `--libxo` option of ps.

Comment: No, im on OSX, and theres no `--libxo` option, at least not in the version I have. https://gist.github.com/jhyland87/6ff0266abc9a9b57690ab28dfc18c180

Comment: @Justin - FYI, OSX's `ps` command is based on [the `ps` command from FreeBSD 6.0](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=FreeBSD+6.0-RELEASE) (released in 2005), which does not include the `--libxo` option. That option [was in fact added to FreeBSD 11](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE), which was released in 2016.